# In Wikipedia's motivating example of wedge product, what happened to $e_1 \wedge e_1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exterior-algebra

Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) has a motivating example for wedge product.

In particular, it was written that:

$
\begin{align}
{\mathbf v}\wedge {\mathbf w} & = (a{\mathbf e}_1 + b{\mathbf e}_2) \wedge (c{\mathbf e}_1 + d{\mathbf e}_2) \\
& = ac{\mathbf e}_1 \wedge {\mathbf e}_1+ ad{\mathbf e}_1 \wedge {\mathbf e}_2+bc{\mathbf e}_2 \wedge {\mathbf e}_1+bd{\mathbf e}_2 \wedge {\mathbf e}_2 \\
& =(ad-bc){\mathbf e}_1 \wedge {\mathbf e}_2
\end{align}
$

It is explained that:

> where the first step uses the distributive law for the exterior
>   product, and the last uses the fact that the exterior product is
>   alternating, and in particular $e_2 ∧ e_1 = −e_1 ∧ e_2$.

In this example, whatever happened to the term associated with $e_1 \wedge e_1$? and $e_2 \wedge e_2$?

Wikipedia doesn't say.

Comment: I think this qustion is not related to differential equations, and that tag can be removed.

Comment: As a wise man once put it: 
«Old MacDonald had a form: $e_i \wedge e_i = 0$»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$e_1\wedge e_1=-e_1\wedge e_1,$$
so $e_1\wedge e_1=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Since the product is alternating,
$$\color{red}{e_1}\wedge\color{blue}{e_1} = -\color{blue}{e_1}\wedge\color{red}{e_1}$$
and therefore
$$e_1\wedge e_1 = 0$$

Comment: The product *is* alternating, I agree, but the first equation you have shows that the product is *antisymmetric*.  The alternating property is what you have in the second equation.  Essentially your statement reads "since the product is alternating, the product is antisymmetric and therefore the product is alternating". ;)

Comment: @Bye_World: So "alternating" does not mean the same as "antisymmetric"? I thought the property you seem to call "alternating" is called "nilpotent".

Comment: A multilinear map $B$ is called alternating if $B(v_1, \dots, v_i, \dots, v_i, \dots, v_n) = 0$ (i.e. if any two arguments $v_i$ are the same then $B$ maps to zero).  A multilinear map is antisymmetric if $B(v_1, \dots, v_i, \dots, v_j, \dots, v_n) = -B(v_1, \dots, v_j, \dots, v_i, \dots, v_n)$ (i.e. switching any two elements produces a negative sign).  It turns out that every antisymmetric bilinear map is also alternating and vice versa (making the two essentially equivalent statements) **so long as the base field is not of characteristic $2$**.

Comment: If you'd rather use the language of a product $\wedge: V\times V \to \bigwedge V$ than a bilinear map, then the first equation results from the product being **anticommutative** and the second shows that that implies that every element of $V$ is **nilpotent**.

Answer (score 1):

The wedge product is defined to be the asymmetric tensors
$$ v_1 \wedge v_2 = v_1 \otimes v_2 - v_2 \otimes v_1 $$
Therefore $e_1 \wedge e_1 = 0$ vanishes.